# Direct solution of the simple harmonic motion.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a method for solving the differential equation of a simple harmonic oscillator,
$$ \mathbf{\ddot{x}}=-k\mathbf{x}$$
without assuming a solution of the form $e^{mx}$ or $A\cos x$ or $B\sin x$?

That is, is there a general method for soving a second order linear differential equation?

Comment: "is there a general method for soving a second order linear differential equation" ... do you know how to use Google?

Answer (score 0):

Hint...write $$\ddot{x}=v\frac{dv}{dx}$$